# Angular2 send create request

Tags: angular, angular-http

We have Spring MVC backend which can get create, update, delete requests as POST request. Is it possible to send such requests with Angular?
I didn't even find create and update requests on http

Comment: Can you provide more info about your REST APIs which is written in Spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have RESTful APIs written in Spring, then you can use Angular to make single page application and Angular internally will have call the REST APIs through one of the module: Angular HTTP

https://angular.io/guide/http

Where you can find, there are components and services.

Component are binded to View.
So best practice says, rather than calling directly http method from component, create Injectable service which will internally call the HTTP methods.

If you are new to Angular and wanted to start from scratch: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

HTTP requests are generally based off GET, POST, PUT and DELETE methods, so the Angular methods correspond to those.  You will need to know which method each of your server's calls respond to, and call the appropriate one.

I would recommend doing a quick read up of the Angular documentation too:  https://angular.io/guide/http. It may shed a bit of light.  But if it is POST calls you're receiving, then you'll probably be be looking at something like this.

```
@Component({
    template: '<div>{{response}}</div>'
})
export class DemoComponent {
    response: string = '';

    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    create(obj) {
        this.http.post('/api/something', obj).subscribe(response => {
            this.response = response;
        }
    }
}
```

Best of luck.